# Manipulate: Display Slider Value in Custom Format

Tags: plotting, manipulate, display, slider

I am plotting two functions using 'Manipulate' and I am trying to change the way the values of certain adjustable parameters are being displayed.
Here is a photo of the plot so I can refer to the exact variable names:
[image]
Briefly put, the plot will depend on two variables and when I display their value, I would like to display the slider value times some number (because I need it in multiples of a certain quantity).

Specifically in connection to the photo: you can see how the E_G variable (named 'g' in the Manipulate sequence) is very small ... here I would like it to be displayed in multiples of a constant kk (already defined, as you can see) times the current value of the t-variable.

The specific case aside, I guess there is a general way to manipulate the way a slider variable is displayed, I just have not found anything yet.
I would really appreciate your help with that!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual code you are using, not an image of the  code, so that readers may copy and run it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to simply rescale the slider limits and variable: Let's say you want to control `x` between `0` and `2`, but show `10*x`. You would do the following:

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{"Value of x: ", x10/10},
 {{x10, 1, "10·x"}, 0, 10}
 ]
```

[image]

The above approach effectively delegates the transformation of the variable to the user: Every time you want to use `x`, you have to write `x10/10`. If you want a more user friendly (but more complicated internally) solution, you can take advantage of [custom `Manipulate` controls](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html#869282457) and the second argument of [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)

First, we define a custom slider function:

```
iTransformedSlider[func_][Dynamic@var_, lims_ : {0, 1}] :=
 Manipulator[
  Dynamic[func@var, (var = InverseFunction[func][#]) &],
  func /@ lims
  ]
transformedSlider[func_] := iTransformedSlider[func][##] &
```

The `iTransformedSlider` trick is necessary since `Manipulate` only accepts expressions with explicit head `Function`. As for how it works: We construct a `Manipulator` using the arguments passed to us (`var` and `lims`), but the apply the transformation function `func` where appropriate. This means: Scaling the displayed value and the limits using `func`, and applying the inverse of `func` when setting `var`. We can then use it simply as:

```
Manipulate[
 Row@{"Value of x: ", x},
 {{x, 1, "10·x"}, 0, 1, transformedSlider[10 # &]}
 ]
```

[image]